# Cocoa App's quit action doesn't work after return NSTerminateLater

Tags: cocoa

In `- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender`
 i return `NSTerminateLater` and launch a window(`win1`) before quit, then in this window i will do some actions(such as launch another window(`win2`)), i can call `[NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];`
to quit App in the `win1`, but it will quit the whole App, then i want only to restore the App's quit feature, because i have delegate function.

`- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return YES;
}`

And i found that right click dock menu "Quit" doesn't work. 
how to do this?

Comment: Can you describe the wanted behaviour, your solution and the current behaviour?

Comment: @Willeke, i want the app can be quit from Menu item after return `NSTerminateLater`

Comment: `NSTerminateLater` stands for "Wait a minute, let met finish something.". If you want to return to return to the normal running state of the app, return `NSTerminateCancel`.

Comment: @Willeke, i use `NSTerminateCancel` then the quit menu can be clicked, but it has no action, it seems the action `terminate:` is not called

Comment: I think `NSTerminateCancel` is not suitable for my project, thanks